# How to spawn a ruby script in a new command prompt window?

Tags: ruby

When I use this code below it works great for non cli programs like notepad.  However, whenever I want to spawn another ruby script or executable, it takes over that command prompt window and I can not see my parent process anymore.  How can I make the spawn command open the script in a new window?

```
pid = spawn(path)
Process.wait pid
```

I have already tried "start path" but that doesn't return the correct pid.  I also tried Process.daemon, but that didn't even do anything. I believe I need to make it open another conhost.exe process because it starts two ruby.exe processes and two cmd.exe processes, but keeps only 1 conhost.exe process.

I am trying to writing a ruby script that spawns other scripts and manages them. Cross platform is ideal, but Windows compatible will do.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this gem [**eye** here](https://github.com/kostya/eye) to manage & monitor processes, works quite well with **start**ing & **stop**ping processes(using PID).